# htaccess redirect - all 404 pages in category to main category page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

htaccess redirect - all 404 pages in category to main category page

Hi

I need advise on Apache htaccess redirect

how do you redirect a bunch of urls with 404 to the category main page?

For e.g: www.mysite.com/category/1.html - deleted and 404d
www.mysite.com/category/2.html - deleted and 404d

etc etc

I need these 404 URL to be redirected to www.mysite.com/category (not category/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this

//404.html > the custom 404 page. You need to create one

ErrorDocument 404 404.html

Comment: I have a custom 404.html - that part is fine. But i need to redirect the purged/deleted page to its category list page. If this page from category1 does not exist, redirect the visitor to category1 main page where all new pages are listed.

Comment: Looks like nobody understood my question: Let me put it this way: HTACCESS REDIRECT www.example.com/category1/all404pages.html TO www.example.com/category1.html AND www.example.com/category2/all404pages.html TO www.example.com/category2.html AND SO ON..